# Unable to Create System DSN

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, odbc, dsn

Environment:
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Operating System

Problem:
(ODBC Data Source Administrator)
Opening Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) -> Click "System DSN" tab.

Error:
ODBC System DSN Warning
You are logged on with non-Administrative privileges.
System DSNs could not be created or modified.

Failed Troubleshooting so far:
Enabled local Administrator account logged in under this account.
Navigated to C:\Windows\System32\ right clicked odbcad32.exe Run as Administrator

Notes:
I am an Administrator on this machine.
The 32-bit version runs fine if I open C:\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe
However, I need the data source to be 64-bit.
I am not experiencing this problem on any of my other 64-bit machines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` was missing, which is where 64-bit odbcad32.exe loads list of DSNs from.

So I just created `ODBC.INI` and `ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources` under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC` and that annoying dialog box went away.

Comment: Hint: If you have the problem with `x32` version and you are running `x64` you need to use the `Wow6432Node`. Therefore this is the new root path: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI`

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a look at the permission on `HKLM\Software\ODBC` and the subkeys. Do you see any non-stock ACLs there? Stock ACLs will contain inherited ACEs only (with no non-inherited ACEs). It sounds like the registry permissions have been played-with.

Edit:

I'm interested in having you look at the registry permissions. Highlight the `HKLM\Software\ODBC` key in Registry Editor and choose *Edit* / *Permissions* from the menu. In the *Advanced* dialog you should see the individual access control entries (ACEs) that make up the access control list (ACL). In a default Windows 7 install there will be 4 items listed (Users, Administrators, SYSTEM, and CREATOR OWNER) and they will all have *MACHINE\SOFTWARE* in their *Inherited From* column.

Comment: In HKLM\Software\ODBC there is just one entry: (Default)
In HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI there is just on entry: (Default)
However, it contains sub-folders: ODBC Drivers -> which only contains three entries (Default), Oracle in instantclient_11_2, and SQL Server Native Client 11.0. There is a folder for each of those as well.  I took a look at another Windows 7 64-bit machine and it contains a lot more entries in the drivers folder and other folders in general like ODBC Core, ODBC Translators, etc.,  Is there some way to repair the ODBC registry entries?

Comment: I dropped on an edit.

Comment: I see the 4 items you listed: Users, Administrators, SYSTEM, CREATOR OWNER.  They all inherit from MACHINE\SOFTWARE.

Permissions:
Users = Read, Administrators = Full Control, SYSTEM = Full Control, CREATOR OWNER = Special.