# Unable to Create MySql 64-bit System DSN on Windows

Tags: windows, mysql, odbc

I have a very similar problem to "[Unable to Create System DSN](https://serverfault.com/questions/485690/unable-to-create-system-dsn)," but none of the fixes suggested there have worked for me.

System: Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise.

I'm trying to create a DSN to use accessing MySQL from powershell.
When I open up `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe` (the default 64-bit ODBC Administrator) and click on the system DSN tab, 
it gives the warning

"You are logged in with a non-administrative privileges. System DSNs could not be created or modified"
I am the sole administrator on the system and am logged in as administrator when this happens. I have also tried starting the ODBC Administrator by right-click run as administrator, same result.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Have checked the permissions on `HKLM/software/odbc`
- Have tried [advice here](http://debugge.com/odbcdsn-you-are-logged-on-with-non-administrative-privileges-system-dsns-could-not-be-created-or-modified-error.db)
- Tried running the WoW64 32-bit version of ODBC  `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` which will allow me to click the system DSN tab and I have added a 32-bit MySQL System DSN from there, FWIW which I was able to do without right-click run as administrator.

[Great article about ODBC here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976)

I guess for now I'll use the 32-bit System DSN, but it would be nice to use the 64-bit if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just launch the "Data Sources (ODBC)" console directly. You need to right click it and choose "Run as Administrator"

I know you are logged in as an Administrator, but you have to start the process in a way that takes full advantage of that.

Alternatively, you can turn UAC off, but that is not recommended.

Comment: Had already tried that also. Sorry I meant to mention that in the original. I'll update the post. Thanks for pointing that out. Regarding UAC, I think I already mentioned that but  maybe I'm confused, is not UAC what I linked to above: http://debugge.com/odbcdsn-you-are-logged-on-with-non-administrative-privileges-system-dsns-could-not-be-created-or-modified-error.db

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a System DSN in the 64-bit Admin with a 32-bit driver, nor in the 32-bit Admin with a 64-bit driver...

What you've described confirms you have a 32-bit ODBC driver for MySQL installed.

Do you have a 64-bit ODBC driver for MySQL ([like these from my employer](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/wizard.php?uda_step1_radio=1&client_application=13&client_language=1&client_interface=3&client_opsys_family=1&client_opsys=x86_64-generic-win-64&client_32_on_64=64&server_dbms_family=8&server_dbms=mys5&server_opsys_family=9999&server_opsys=other&enterprise_level=0&dbms_server_install=2)) installed?  It seems likely that you do not, and that installing one will get you where you want to go.